# Switching Rows into Columns

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have a table proj_ctc_grp_usr:

```
USER_ID PROJ_ID CTC_GRP_ID
2          1     1
2          1     2
3          1     1
3          1     2
4          2     2
```

Table**ctc_grp:**

```
CTC_GRP_ID     CTC_GRP_DS
1             Bank Contact
2            Dept2
```

Table**User**

```
USER_ID USER_FIRST_NM   USER_LST_NM
2          saravanakumar    rajkumar
3          Soosai           Antony
4          Adam           Allen
```

I am using the below query:

```
SELECT  *
            FROM    (   SELECT PROJ.PROJ_ID,           
                                CTC_GRP_DS                               
                        FROM  dbo.Project PROJ  
                         left join dbo.PROJ_CTC_GRP_USER  PCGU on PROJ.PROJ_ID = PCGU.PROJ_ID
                         left join dbo.CTC_GRP CG on PCGU.CTC_GRP_ID = CG.CTC_GRP_ID
                    ) data

                    PIVOT
                    (   MAX(CTC_GRP_DS)
                        FOR CTC_GRP_DS IN ([Bank Contact],[Dept2])
                    ) pvt4
```

and getting below output...

```
PROJ_ID Bank Contact    Dept2
1   Bank Contact    Dept2
2   NULL              Dept2
```

I am trying to display it in below form...

```
PROJ_ID Bank Contact                          Dept2
1   saravanakumarRajkumar, soosaiAntony   saravanakumarRajkumar, soosaiAntony 
2   NULL                                    AllenAdam...
```

I tried it & end up with no luck...Pls help on it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things that you need to do to get the result.

First, your current query using the PIVOT is not correct. You are attempting to get the `MAX(CTC_GRP_DS)` for each `CTC_GRP_DS` in your data.  You actually want to return the name for each `CTC_GRP_DS` in your data.

Second, you need to concatenate the first and last names together and you also want to concatenate the list of names for each project. You can use `FOR XML PATH` to do this concatenation.

```
;with cte as
(
  SELECT PCGU.PROJ_ID,
    name = u.USER_LST_NM + ', '+ u.USER_FIRST_NM,           
    CTC_GRP_DS                               
  FROM  dbo.[user] u  
  left join dbo.proj_ctc_grp_usr  PCGU 
    on u.USER_ID = PCGU.USER_ID
  left join dbo.CTC_GRP CG 
    on PCGU.CTC_GRP_ID = CG.CTC_GRP_ID
) 
select *
from
(
  select c1.proj_id,
    c1.CTC_GRP_DS,
    STUFF(
         (SELECT ', ' + c2.name
          FROM cte c2
          where c1.proj_id = c2.proj_id
            and c1.CTC_GRP_DS = c2.CTC_GRP_DS
          FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 1, '')  AS name
  from cte c1
) d
pivot
(
  max(name)
  for CTC_GRP_DS in ([Bank Contact],[Dept2])
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e1427/11)

Comment: I see now that I had forgotten to list up all users in my solution. This FOR XML PATH was a quite elegant way of solving this. I've not used that before. Goes straight into my toolbox. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are very close. But you're aggregate function in the pivot should be the value you want after you have pivoted. So since you are using CTC_GRP_DS both in the aggregate and in the FOR, you end up with the pivoted column names as values. Hopefully you can use the query below. Note: The Project table you had in your query you had not presented so you might have to include that table.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT      
        p.[PROJ_ID]
        ,c.CTC_GRP_DS
    ,u.USER_FIRST_NM + ', ' + u.USER_LST_NM as UserName
    FROM [proj_ctc_grp_usr] p
    LEFT JOIN
        ctc_grp c
    ON
        p.CTC_GRP_ID = c.CTC_GRP_ID
    LEFT JOIN
        [User] u
    ON
        p.[User_ID] = u.[User_ID]
) d
PIVOT(
    MAX(UserName)
    FOR CTC_GRP_DS IN ([Bank Contact], Dept2)
)p
```